# How can I download Eclipse for all languages?

Tags: eclipse

For Eclipse I see various versions like C++, Java, PHP, Python, etc.

Is there any Eclipse which has all those languages and plugins in one package?

It may be 3GB in size but I want all plugins in one package.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the [Yoxos on-demand download service](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start).

Select all packages you want on the left, and then download.

[image]

Apart from that, there's no standalone download with all packages to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

What you see on the Eclipse website is just a collection of common Eclipse configurations, but you can also install a base Eclipse version and then add all the packets you need.

This is the [official documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-124.htm) explaining how to do it.